# Task Activitydate in user timezone

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, datetime, timezone

Trying to convert DAteTime field in local user time zone with following code but get an error:

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [Date].format(String, String)

```
TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
List<Task> allTasks = [Select id, ActivityDate, Description, Subject from Task where Id IN :taskIds];
for (Task t : allTasks)
{
    DateTime dt = t.ActivityDate.format('M/d/yyyy hh:mm a',tz.getId());
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `DateTime.format()` method always return string not DateTime.. Yes also format is method of dateTime not date

Comment: .format is method of dateTime not date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActivityDate is date on [Task object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) so you need to convert that into datetime first.

[image]

```
TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
    List<Task> allTasks = [Select id, ActivityDate, Description, Subject from Task where Id IN :taskIds];
    for (Task t : allTasks)
    {
        DateTime activityDate = t.activitydate;
        String dt =  activityDate.format('M/d/yyyy hh:mm a',tz.getId());
        system.debug(dt);
    }
```

Above code will work for you.